# How to stop input from blurring within directive

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have a custom directive that should have the following functionality:

-display button upon load

-show input box and expand box when button is clicked

-show clear text icon when user types into text box

-clear text when icon is clicked and re-focus on text box

-minimize text box and show button when user clicks away from text box and clear text icon

Here's what I have so far: http://jsfiddle.net/Z6RzD/161/

My problem is that when a user clicks on the clear icon, the text box's blur function is fired and the box loses focus.

I tried creating a scope variable in my controller that will let me know which element has been clicked on. I then tried to share this variable in my directive's blur function but it comes up undefined.

```
$scope.clickElem;

$document.bind('click',function(e){
    $scope.clickElem = e.target;
    $scope.$apply();
    console.log($scope.clickElem);
});
```

Any ideas on how to fix this? I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's ok for you to use HTML5, you can just replace `<input type="text">` with `<input type="search">` and get the clear behavior for free. Here's your [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Z6RzD/162/) modified to do that.

Comment: Too easy. Thanks again Michael!

Answer (score 0):

try this..

```
var scope;
$('ELEMENT').click(function(e){
scope = e.target;
});
```

that should most def. not return undefined.